# How can I create a probability distribution plot for categorical attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I create a probability distribution plot for categorical attributes?

I tried to use `sns.distplot`, but get the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`.

However when I run `sns.countplot(x="WAKE", data=df, palette="Greens_d")`, I get a correct count plot.

df =

```
ID   WAKE
1    H
2    H
3    L
4    H
5    M
6    M
7    H
8    L
```

Comment: What do you mean? The `countplot` does exactly what I thought you were asking.

Comment: @Felix: Basically I want to see the probabilities on the Y axis, not the absolute count. That's the only difference.

Comment: I answered with what I think is the solution. It's not quite as visually pleasing, but I'm sure with some fiddling with the plotting options it can be taken to a more acceptable form.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly Seaborn, but I hope basic Matplotlib will do.

You can reduce the categories to numericals and plot a histogram. This histogram you can then use as a density histogram to normalize it. I urge you to read the documentations of each of the functions here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Wake'] = ['H', 'H', 'L', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'H', 'L']

# Reduce categories to numbers
vals = df['Wake'].values
uniq, idx = np.unique(vals, return_inverse=True)

# View results as groups (just for show)
df['C'] = idx
df.groupby('Wake').count()

# Substract 0.5 to center to the indices
i = idx - 0.5
plt.hist(i, bins=np.arange(0, idx.max()+2, 1)-0.5, density=True)
plt.show()
```